# the default value for an HTML <select> element not working

Tags: html

I want my dropdown to have the default value of "No" `value=0` and i used `selected` but when the program runs it doenst show the "No" after the page load. Ive tested my code in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yydcd9n/), and its working correctly. Ive reloaded the cache before running the program but no success.

Comment: It does show now when I test it. Probably you are testing it by loading the page, setting the value to Yes, then refreshing it. The browser remembers the value when simply refreshing.

Comment: What about if you set `selected="selected"`?

Comment: @Quentin tried to set Yes and refresh (ctrl+r) also cleaned the browser history and tested with other browser and no success.

Comment: @EduardoEscobar doesnt take any effect in the view with that